# Selected Option with JQuery - Works in Chrome BUT not on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have this Select:

```
  <div>
    <select id="action" multiple></select>
  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="array.js"></script>

  <script>$('#action option[value="transferred"]').attr("selected", "selected");</script>
```

Array.js is populating the Select with Options. Once the page is loaded no option is selected (despite the JQuery script that appears last in the code above).

When I try to run that same JQuery instruction in chrome, on the same page, the 'transferred' option gets selected.

Why instead reloading the page doesn't select any option as if the JQuery script is not working?

**EDIT:**
I understand from comments that the populating script works with a promise.
I then moved the JQuery script inside the populating array.js file as follows:

```
function populateLists() {
  d3.json('data.json').then( function(data) {
    const keys = [
      "coin_lab",
      "action",
      "from",
      "to"]

    var list = new Object;

    keys.forEach(key => {
        let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item[key]))];
        list[key] = unique;
    })

    $('select').empty();
    list.action.forEach(act => {
      $('select').append(new Option(act, act))
    })
  })
  .then($('#action option[value="transferred"]').attr("selected", "selected");
}

populateLists();
```

unfortunately this does not work as it is problably the wrong way to use .then().
any help?

Comment: Is the script tag with the jquery code *after* the element it references?

Comment: yes as in the code above, the select #action appears before the script with JQuery.
Array.js that populates the Select also appears before the script that selects the option. Does that mean that array.js runs before the JQuery? or there is something that I don't know?

Comment: OK...does that option also exist on page load, or is it populated with javascript asynchronously? Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: it gets populated by the array.js above

Comment: Depends what array.js does. If it has asynchronous code then the option may not exist at the time the jQuery runs

Comment: even when I put that JQuery line inside teh populating script (array.js) it still does not work

Comment: Need to show us what array.js does. Sounds like a synchronicity problem

Comment: There is a D3.js code that uses Promises, that is probably the problem? how can I make sure that the selecting JQuery line executes after that? shall I put it inside a .then()?

Comment: Yes you would need to do that. Promises are asynchronous

Comment: `then()` requires a function argument. Change to `.then(_ => $('#action....)`

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked. what is the correct way to post the solution now? shall I answer it myself or just edit my question?